# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application' [Deploying Django to AWS]

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy a Django application at ElasticBeanstalk from AWS.

I have followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-deploy) tutorial probably 6 or 7 times.

tried to deploy from Linux and from windows machine in either way I end up getting:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'` or `web: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'application'.`

the other files are blank because I've tried with a project of mine and now I'm trying with a blank one.

django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: c2exchange.wsgi:application
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'c2exchange.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

those are my files:

[image]

Logs:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1250] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1250)
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1244] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1244] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1258] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1258] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1264] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1264
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1264] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: worker.init_process()
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: super().init_process()
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.load_wsgi()
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.callable = self.load()
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1264] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1264)
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1258] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 24 22:23:48 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:48 +0000] [1258] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1272] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1272] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1278] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1278
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1278] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: worker.init_process()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: super().init_process()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.load_wsgi()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.callable = self.load()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1278] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1278)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1272] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1272] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1286] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1286] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1292] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1292
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1292] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: worker.init_process()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: super().init_process()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.load_wsgi()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: self.callable = self.load()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1292] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1292)
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1286] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Sep 24 22:23:49 ip-172-31-33-134 web: [2021-09-24 22:23:49 +0000] [1286] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.


----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
172.31.37.198 - - [24/Sep/2021:18:12:26 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://c2deving.eba-zv3cph3u.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36" "177.142.87.161"
172.31.8.207 - - [24/Sep/2021:18:15:30 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://c2deving.eba-zv3cph3u.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36" "177.142.87.161"
172.31.37.198 - - [24/Sep/2021:19:08:15 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "htt
```

Comment: Are you using Amazon Linux 1 or Amazon Linux 2? Unfortunately, the config file will need to be different depending on which version you are using.

Comment: Amazon Linux 2, am i missing some file?

Comment: Can you show the contents of `eb logs`?

Comment: Having you committed all these files ? If you have initialised git for your project, it deploys the latest commit from current branch - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cli-git.html

Comment: i've tried before and tried yesterday either, still same problem.

Comment: did you even find a solution to this?

Comment: i didn't, so stopped trying with Elastic Beanstalk and deployed on a EC2 @alphazwest

Comment: @lucasrf27 FWIW -- I finally got mine to disappear and work as expected after dealing with some other upstream issues. It was having trouble in the build phase -- just not in an error-generating capacity. It was evident b/c even with the correct .config settings -- the `wsgi` path wasn't being updated in the online ELB console view and still reflected just `application` vs. `project.wsgi.py:application`. For me, it was an SQLite3 issue that was resolved by switching to `postgres` which made sense anyway.

Comment: @alphazwest appreciate so much the feedback, definitely will try with postgres soon

Answer (score 1):

Try
if you are using a mac, make sure you are zipping the files,
not at the lop level.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo ".ebextentions" instead of ".ebextensions"
2. Since you have a .gitignore I expect that you use git for your project. I had the same problem once, because I did not commit all changes before "eb deploy"

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo ".ebextentions" instead of ".ebextensions"

[2.In the configuration module go to software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRTiL.png)

[3.Then in the WSGIPath add *c2exchange.wsgi:application* instead of *application*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIAZA.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).